# Open source java library to read outlook emails, calendar etc

Tags: java

I am looking for an open source java lib to read emails, calendar, contacts from Microsoft outlook. Do you know any of these lib or workaround?

Right now the requirement is to only read the data and present it on jsp page.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running on Windows you can probably use [JaWin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/). It is an open source library that wraps COM object and provides you a Java API to access them. As far as I remember its distribution contains example of how to connect to MS Exchange server.

Other similar packages I know are

- [Jintegra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) (costs some money)
- [Jinterop](http://j-interop.org/) (open source too)

Both libraries implement DCOM protocol in Java, so you can run application that uses them on any platform and connect to exchange server.

Other way is to use POP3 or SMTP protocol also supported by Exchange. There are a lot of packages that support them, e.g. JavaMail.

And the last way: if your application is running on client side, i.e. on the client's computer it can parse files created by outlook itself. I do not remember where these files are stored but I remember that many years ago I have discovered the issue and saw that all emails are stored in file system in clear text format.

EDIT: Recently I found out [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/): other library that uses JNI (like JaWin).

Comment: This JaWin looks promising. Let me try these libs and let you know. Great job AlexR!!! You save me hrs of research.

Comment: NP, I knew it. I was using these libraries for 3 years and had many fun :(. Memory leak in JaWin even caused me to travel abroad and discover the problem at customer's site.

Comment: I was wondering if you know any lib like Java Outlook Connector (JOC) but it should be open source.