# Can selenium be used for testing email contents of an email in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: email, testing, selenium

I am using Selenium for testing a web Application.
One of the functionality is "Upload a file"-

As soon as i upload a file, a cron job is executed on the back end to upload my file. Once, the file is uploaded, the user receives an email notifying that the file is uploaded containing all the information about the file.

I receive this email on Microsoft Outlook.

Is there any way i can test this functionality and the contents of the email in the Microsoft Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

The best bet to test email is to ask to the email server (and preferrably configure it on IMAP if a client is connected to it :-)). A java mail client is a breeze to do in Java with [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/)

If you really want to connect to Outlook, then you can use a connector, as suggested by `@ABP`. See [this SO question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324856/open-source-java-library-to-read-outlook-emails-calendar-etc)

If you really really (really ?) want to use selenium, you'll be stuck because the basis of Selenium is its drivers (for Firefox, Chrome, etc) and there is no driver for Outlook (Selenium is web site automation, after all). The API itself is for clicking on links, but no retreiving emails

If you're adventurous, you can bet on [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) which is a powerful desktop automation solution that can at least open Outlook, check emails, and check if an email subject match a certain pattern. But it is OCR,and when you start doing OCR for testing... things can go bad really really fast

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a  web version of your email. Outlook is the email client. Do you have any web based email client, you can do it then. I don't think you can use Selenium to read from outlook.. but in Java I think you will find Outlook connectors that you can use probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xyz@company.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

//Click on Arrange by

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tdAB")).click();
```

//click on selection to arrange

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#spnT")).click();
```

//Come to the top of the list

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);

//Procedure to find first email by subject and click the link in it

    Thread.sleep(5000);
List<WebElement> email = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#divSubject"));

for(WebElement emailsub : email){

    if(emailsub.getText().equals("<email subject>") == true){
           emailsub.click();
           break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly requirements in my project. I have sorted this by using JAVAX MAIL API and JAVA. Additionally,it checks for attachment and if yes, read the pdf as well.

```
 // Dependencies & Imports
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.nio.file.Files;
  import java.nio.file.Path;
  import java.nio.file.Paths;
  import java.util.Properties;

  import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentInfo;
  import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentInfoUtil;
  import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentType;

  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
  import com.testautomationguru.utility.PDFUtil;
  import javax.mail.Flags;
  import javax.mail.Folder;
  import javax.mail.Message;
  import javax.mail.MessagingException;
  import javax.mail.Multipart;
  import javax.mail.Part;
  import javax.mail.Session;
  import javax.mail.Store;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
  import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

  public OutlookEmail(String username, String password, String server, EmailsFolder 
  inbox) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "<your email>", "<your password>");


    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Total Message:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Message:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message mail : messages) {
        if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {

            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");

            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));
            System.out.println("Has Attachments: " + hasAttachments(mail));

        }
    }
}

public boolean hasAttachments(Message email) throws Exception {

    // suppose 'message' is an object of type Message
    String contentType = email.getContentType();
    System.out.println(contentType);

    if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("multipart/mixed")) {
        // this message must contain attachment
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) email.getContent();

        for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                System.out.println("Attached filename is:" + part.getFileName());

                MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) part;
                String fileName = mimeBodyPart.getFileName();

                String destFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Resources\\";

                File fileToSave = new File(fileName);
                mimeBodyPart.saveFile(destFilePath + fileToSave);

                // download the pdf file in the resource folder to be read by PDFUTIL api.

                PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();
                String pdfContent = pdfUtil.getText(destFilePath + fileToSave);

                System.out.println("******---------------********");
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Started reading the pdfContent of the attachment:==");


                System.out.println(pdfContent);

                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("******---------------********");

                Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(destFilePath + fileToSave);
                Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public String getEmailBody(Message email) throws IOException, MessagingException {

    String line, emailContentEncoded;
    StringBuffer bufferEmailContentEncoded = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(email.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        bufferEmailContentEncoded.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println("**************************************************");

    System.out.println(bufferEmailContentEncoded);

    System.out.println("**************************************************");

    emailContentEncoded = bufferEmailContentEncoded.toString();

    if (email.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/related")) {

        emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(emailContentEncoded.indexOf("base64") + 6);
        emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(0, emailContentEncoded.indexOf("Content-Type") - 1);

        System.out.println(emailContentEncoded);

        String emailContentDecoded = new String(new Base64().decode(emailContentEncoded.toString().getBytes()));
        return emailContentDecoded;
    }

    return emailContentEncoded;

}
```

Here is POMs dependencies section:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev105-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.testautomationguru.pdfutil/pdf-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testautomationguru.pdfutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdf-util</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Checking pdf file and whether is corrupted or not -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.simplemagic</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplemagic</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you please share the imports and dependencies which works for you .. It will be helpful with anyone who try your shared code, javax.mail-api only dependency doesn't works and also I guess you have created some objects at class level which you haven't copy here

Comment: @ShubhamJain added asked dependencies and imports

Comment: Thanks @Atul for adding imports, from dependencies I mean pom details which you have added in pom.xml, it will help to see the version which is compatible with this functionality

Comment: @ShubhamJain POM added