# Create an E-Mail and view it before sending in Microsoft Outlook with Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an application with `Spring Boot` and have to send email via Outlook, because that's mailing application used in my company. I don't want to send it automatically because user needs to view the email first and send it manually.

I don't know if is it possible, to create an email for Outlook, fill in details (i.e. body, subject) and show it for the user to view so that user can click send button?

I hope somebody knows how this could be done, or just give me the answer it's not possible, so I can stop searching.

Comment: you can create a custom layout with send button etc. then fill it with the stuff needed and if user clicks on send button, it will be send. no need for outlook. there might be a smoother solution, but its the fastest thing i could think of. have a look at thislink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324856/open-source-java-library-to-read-outlook-emails-calendar-etc

Comment: It can be done.

Comment: If you want to do it in Outlook you probably should check whether Outlook provides an api to create email drafts. If such an api exists (and I assume there is one) you can call it from Java, just how (and how easy this is) would depend on the api itself. But as XtremeBaumer said you don't need Outlook to send emails so you might want to circumvent that and provide a preview directly from within your application.